# How to set style of a password text input in React-native

Tags: android, react-native

I couldn't manage to change the style of `TextInput` in **React Native** when the `secureTextEntry` prop set to true. Also the default style of input changes, I understood this is due to android native behaviour. The below code does not change the style unless I unset `secureTextEntry`.

```
<TextInput secureTextEntry={true} style={{color: "white"}}/>
```

I have a login form and having different styles for email input and password input is disturbing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

UPDATED

Seems like the following PR will fix the issue:

[PR Link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6064)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known RN issue. You can track it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4435). Unless you submit a PR, I think we'll have to wait for that feature to come.

Comment: Seems like the following PR will fix the issue. Thanks. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6064

Answer (score 4):

```js
<TextInput
          placeholder={'Environment'}
          placeholderTextColor="#202020"
          secureTextEntry={true}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

[This PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6563) has now been merged to fix it, and it should probably land in `0.23`.

If like me, you don't want to wait for it, or can't upgrade easily, you can use [this module](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-text-input) I created, as described in [this blog post](http://blog.bamlab.fr/how-to-colorize-password-inputs-in-react-native-android/).

Basically, install the module with:

```
npm install --save react-native-text-input
```

Link it to your native code: I strongly recommend the use of  [RNPM](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm) to link native modules:

```
npm install -g rnpm
rnpm link react-native-text-input
```

Now you can replace:

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
```

by:

```
import TextInput from 'react-native-text-input';
```

And tadaaaaa!
Your input is now white :)

The `TextInput` from this module is actually a copy-paste from the default React Native one, with the fix in the PR above added.